# UIImageView Allocating Memory Every Time Image Changed - How To Release?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, memory-management

I'm trying to create an application that allows users to go through a set of images like a magazine. I've got one UIView class on top of the AppDelegate and on swipe to the left/right I'm either going forward or backward a page. My problem is that when I swipe and change the image source the program keeps allocating more memory, and I'm not certain where/how to release the previously allocated memory. I've looked in to the difference between imageNamed and imageWithContentsOfFile and I believe I'm using those correctly so I'm stumped. Any help would be much appreciated!

AppDelegate.h

```
@interface AppDelegate : NSObject  {
    UIWindow *window;
    MagazineWebViewController *webViewController;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWindow *window;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet MagazineWebViewController *webViewController;
- (void)goToA:(NSNumber *)page;
@end
```

AppDelegate.m

```
@implementation AppDelegate
@synthesize window, webViewController;
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application {
    webViewController = [[MagazineWebViewController alloc] init];
    NSNumber *page = [NSNumber numberWithInt:1];
    [webViewController setPage:page];
    [window addSubview:webViewController.view];
    [window makeKeyAndVisible];
}
- (void)goToA:(NSNumber *)page {
    UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", page] ofType:@"png"]];
    webViewController.imageView.image = image;
    [image release];
    [webViewController setPage:page];
}
- (void)dealloc {
    [webViewController release];
    webViewController = nil;
    [window release];
    [super dealloc];
}
@end
```

MagazineWebViewController.h

`@interface MagazineWebViewController : UIViewController {
    UIImageView *imageView;
    NSNumber *page;
}
@property (nonatomic, assign)NSNumber *page;
@property (nonatomic, retain)UIImageView *imageView;
- (void)swipeLeft;
- (void)swipeRight;
- (void)tableOfContents;
@end`

MagazineWebViewController.m

`@implementation MagazineWebViewController
@synthesize page, tocController, imageView;
- (id)init {
    UINavigationBar *navBar = [[UINavigationBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 768, 60)];
    navBar.tintColor = [UIColor blackColor];

    UIBarButtonItem *contents = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Table of Contents" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(tableOfContents)]; 
    UINavigationItem *item = [[UINavigationItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Title"];
    item.leftBarButtonItem = contents;
    item.hidesBackButton = YES;
    [navBar pushNavigationItem:item animated:NO];
    [contents release];
    [item release];
    [self.view addSubview:navBar];
    [navBar release];

    self.imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 40, 768, 984)];
    UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"1" ofType:@"png"]];
    self.imageView.image = image;
    [image release];
    self.imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleToFill;

    UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeLeft = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(swipeLeft)];
    swipeLeft.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft;
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:swipeLeft];
    [swipeLeft release];

    UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeRight = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(swipeRight)];
    swipeRight.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight;
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:swipeRight];
    [swipeRight release];

    [self.view addSubview:self.imageView];

    [self.imageView release];

    return self;
}
- (void)swipeLeft {
    int pageNum = [page intValue];

    if (pageNum < 115) {
        pageNum++;
        UIViewAnimationTransition trans = UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlUp;
        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
        [UIView setAnimationTransition:trans forView:self.view.window cache:YES];
        BaseballMagazine2011AppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
        [appDelegate goToA:[NSNumber numberWithInt:pageNum]];
        [UIView commitAnimations];
    }
}
- (void)swipeRight {
    int pageNum = [page intValue];

    if (pageNum > 1) {
        pageNum--;

        UIViewAnimationTransition trans = UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlDown;
        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
        [UIView setAnimationTransition:trans forView:self.view.window cache:YES];
        BaseballMagazine2011AppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
        [appDelegate goToA:[NSNumber numberWithInt:pageNum]];
        [UIView commitAnimations];
    }
}
- (void)tableOfContents {
}
- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Release any cached data, images, etc. that aren't in use.
}
- (void)viewDidUnload {
    [imageView release];
    imageView = nil;
    [page release];
    page = nil;
    [tocController release];
    tocController = nil;
    [super viewDidUnload];
}
- (void)dealloc {
    [imageView release];
    imageView = nil;
    [page release];
    page = nil;
    [super dealloc];
}
@end`

Comment: Where do you invoke `[super init]`? This may be the reason why you're experiencing some issues...

Comment: There are no obvious leaks in your code and this memory is likely to be flushed as required by the system. In any case you could try setting the `image` property to nil in your `goToA:` method and see if it helps i.e. `if (webViewController.imageView.image) webViewController.imageView.image = nil;`. Also after you release `image` on the same method you can try and set it to nil as well.d

Comment: Unfortunately neither of those has fixed the problem. Instruments is telling me it's allocating Malloc and CFString a lot.

Comment: Did you ever find the solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your AppDelegate.m, Try prefacing each reference to webViewController with 'self.'. For example:

self.webViewController = [[MagazineWebViewController alloc] init];

By not referencing the property with self, you are bypassing the properties auto generated setters and getters. And since you set this property to retain, this would bypasses some memory handling logic. I'm pretty sure that is your issue... Hope this helps!

Comment: Also in MagazineWebViewController.m there are several instances of imageView in your viewdidUnload and Dealloc method that you should also preface with 'self.'

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because you alloc every time an UIImage (like said in the comments).

Did you try not doing allocations ?

```
self.imageView.image = [ UIImage imageNamed:@"1.png" ];
```

I think you won't have any problem with this.

But it's difficult to say where come from the leak without all your program ^^
Maybe a retain property or something like that.

Comment: I originally had it like that with the same results. I changed it from imageNamed to imageWithContentsOfFile because imageNamed caches the images. What's posted above is all of the code being run. I have a TableOfContentsViewController.h/m but I have the method to call that controller blank.